# how to make the link between my 2 sql tables?

Tags: php, sql

I cannot correctly make the link between my 2 tables, I have a table that represents my users and another with appointments but I would like to make the link between the 2 to be able to display the appointments users.

**My reservation table looks like this :**

[tablebooking][image: 1]

**My user table looks like this :**

[tableusers][image: 2]

What I Tried :

[test]

[image: 3]

Comment: seems like a simple inner join , what have you tried ? also provide sample data and desired output ? also what is PK_FK between two table?

Comment: Before having a desired output I must make the link between the 2 tables I must create a secondary key?

Comment: yes if you don't have any already , you have to link two tables using foreign key , so you have to add userid column in your booking table and make it foreign key linked to user table

Comment: @eshirvana I add an image of what I tried (i use phpmyadmin )

Comment: @piotro Yes thats the idea. Can you tell whats not working now?

Comment: Already I looked at my site could not work very well because I use if (! Isset ($ _ SESSION ['id']) so when I change "id" to "userid" it breaks my code and I create 2 key but I do not have the link between the 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your appointment functionality is one to one relation like one appointment will have only one member then you can use below query(query followed fields from your screenshots)

```
SELECT 
M.*, B.* 
FROM
members AS M
INNER JOIN bookings AS B ON B.userid = M.userid
```

OR

if you want to have more than one members in one appointment, you need to have tables as below

[YOUR_USERS_TABLE_NAME] => Users list

[YOUR_BOOKINGS_TABLE_NAME] => List of appointments created

[YOUR_BOOKING_MEMBERS_TABLE_NAME] => It should have list of appointment id and members id(one(appointment) to many(users) relation)

and query will be like below

```
SELECT 
B.*, U.* 
FROM
[YOUR_BOOKINGS_TABLE_NAME] AS B
INNER JOIN [YOUR_BOOKING_MEMBERS_TABLE_NAME] AS M ON M.bookingid = B.id
INNER JOIN [YOUR_USERS_TABLE_NAME] AS U on M.userid = U.id
GROUP BY B.id, U.id
```

Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please add user_id in your bookings table and then run below query in your phpmyadmin.

```
select * from bookings as b INNER JOIN users as u ON u.id = b.user_id
```

Thanks.

Comment: error : The table 'bookingcalendar.users' does not exist

Answer (score -1):

You probably must use an external table to connect this tables.
EX:

```
foo{
  id: primary,
  idTableUser: external key,
  idTableBooking: external key
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily true. Depending on the context, he might not need another table.